# Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p

Tags: emacs

What is Emacs complaining about. This error happens to me every once in a while, but I'm new to the world of Emacs, and not so expert in C. Now, emacs is stopping me there and doesn't even let me open a parenthesis to keep coding? What does this error mean?

[image: emacs error]

**EDIT**:
My Emacs version:

[image: emacs version]

My debugger info:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p (1953 . 3706))
  c-looking-at-inexpr-block((1953 . 3706) (1953 . 3706))
  c-inside-bracelist-p(3742 ((1953 . 3706) (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 9156 (9046 . 9137) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 9156 (9046 . 9137) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 9156 (9046 . 9137) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 9156 (9046 . 9137) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 9156 (9046 . 9137) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) 3742 (1953 . 3706) ...))
  c-guess-basic-syntax()
  c-indent-line()
  indent-according-to-mode()
  c-electric-continued-statement()
  abbrev-insert(while #("while" 0 5 (fontified t face font-lock-keyword-face)) 9785 9790)
  #[0 "\304 \211@A\211@A\211@A\211@A\n\211\205Q\305`\306\"\305\306\"\2042\307\310 !\2042\311 \210\312   $V\203O`U\203Ob\210\266\202\266\204\207" [noninteractive last-abbrev-text last-abbrev last-abbrev-location abbrev--before-point copy-marker t window-minibuffer-p selected-window undo-boundary abbrev-insert] 20 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  apply(#[0 "\304 \211@A\211@A\211@A\211@A\n\211\205Q\305`\306\"\305\306\"\2042\307\310 !\2042\311 \210\312 $V\203O`U\203Ob\210\266\202\266\204\207" [noninteractive last-abbrev-text last-abbrev last-abbrev-location abbrev--before-point copy-marker t window-minibuffer-p selected-window undo-boundary abbrev-insert] 20 "\n\n(fn)"] nil)
  #[771 ":\2030@\301=\203\300@\302A\"\303#\207\304@\305\306\307\310\311\312\300!\313\"\314\315%A##\207\304\316\"\207" [(#0) t append nil apply apply-partially make-byte-code 642 "\300@#\207" vconcat vector [] 7 "\n\n(fn FUNS GLOBAL &rest ARGS)" #[0 "\304 \211@A\211@A\211@A\211@A\n\211\205Q\305`\306\"\305\306\"\2042\307\310 !\2042\311 \210\312    $V\203O`U\203Ob\210\266\202\266\204\207" [noninteractive last-abbrev-text last-abbrev last-abbrev-location abbrev--before-point copy-marker t window-minibuffer-p selected-window undo-boundary abbrev-insert] 20 "\n\n(fn)"]] 12 "\n\n(fn FUNS GLOBAL ARGS)"](nil nil nil)
  expand-abbrev()
  self-insert-command(1)
  c-electric-paren(nil)
  call-interactively(c-electric-paren nil nil)
```

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? (`M-x emacs-version`). Does it still happen with `abbrev-mode` disabled? If you can reliably trigger the error, see whether you can replicate it with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this code, though, so I might be missing something, but it looks to me like either a bug in `c-inside-bracelist-p`, or a invalid `paren-state` has been generated. The `paren-state` elements can be cons cells, and while some of the code takes that into account, the call to `c-looking-at-inexpr-block` uses an argument which is just `(car paren-state)`, which might not be an integer, but which is subsequently used as if it were (hence the error). I don't know whether it's valid to have two cons cells in succession in `paren-state`, but that's the case which causes the error.

Comment: I think you should probably `M-x report-emacs-bug`, if you can't find a relevant bug report already.

Comment: If you want this fixed, the first step is to setup a minimally reproducible example.
Give an Emacs version, a C test file, and **minimal** config (`emacs -q` preferred).
Posting an image is rarely helpful.

Comment: Emacs version 24.3.1. I was able to replicate the error, in fact I couldn't get it to go away. I indented the whole buffer, however, and no more errors for now. I will try the emacs -Q when it comes back again.

Comment: @abo-abo Agree, if I knew how to replicate it. What I wanted to know (if you read my question) is what does it mean? what is the problem.

Comment: mimoralea: Well the error `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p (1953 . 3706))` is because `(1953 . 3706)` isn't a number or a marker (and indeed it isn't; it's a cons cell). That's what the error *means*, but that doesn't actually help you directly -- the bug is in whatever code that allowed things to reach that point in the first place.

Comment: This seems to be [Emacs Bug#12266](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12266)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Lisp debugger to find out more precisely what is happening.

1. Load the *source* (not byte-compiled) files **`cc-cmds.el`** (which defines  `c-indent-line`) and **`cc-engine.el`** (which defines `c-guess-basic-syntax`, `c-inside-bracelist-p`, and `c-looking-at-inexpr-block`).

   (Use `M-x load-library cc-cmds.el` and `M-x load-library cc-engine.el` - and don't forget the `.el`.)
2. Open those two source files in a separate frame (`C-x 5 f`), and navigate to the functions you will follow with the debugger. This is so you can more easily see the context around what the debugger is doing.
3. Then `M-x debug-on-entry c-indent-line`.

   Use `d` to step through the debugger. You can use `c` to skip through any step for which you don't care to dive into the details.

You could start with `M-x debug-on-entry c-looking-at-inexpr-block` etc., but that might not provide you with enough context to see what's happening. You can also start by being liberal with `c` instead of `d`, to quickly determine where you want to slow down and see the details. IOW, run the debugger multiple times to provoke the error, using a binary search to narrow down where you want to focus on the details (using `d`).